# How can I find the source code for scipy.stats.mvn?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability-theory

I was using the function `mvn.mvnun()` in the `scipy.stats` module to calculate the CDF of a given multivariate normal distribution in my paper. The reviewer asked me how I estimated the CDF since the CDF has no closed-form. I guess a sampling method might be used. To find out how it works, I searched the `scipy` source code repo. However, in the `scipy.stats` [folder](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/stats), I didn't see `mvn.py`, I saw [`mvn.pyf`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/mvn.pyf) instead.

In the file, `mvn.mvnun` seems to be defined as follows,

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

python module mvn ! in 
    interface  ! in :mvn
        subroutine mvnun(d,n,lower,upper,means,covar,maxpts,abseps,releps,value,inform) ! in :mvn:mvndst.f
            integer intent(hide) :: d=shape(means,0)
            integer intent(hide) :: n=shape(means,1)
            double precision dimension(d) :: lower
            double precision dimension(d) :: upper
            double precision dimension(d,n) :: means
            double precision dimension(d,d) :: covar
            integer intent(optional) :: maxpts=d*1000
            double precision intent(optional) :: abseps=1e-6
            double precision intent(optional) :: releps=1e-6
            double precision intent(out) :: value
            integer intent(out) :: inform
        end subroutine mvnun
```

However, there is no detailed definition of that function. I was wondering where I can find the source code for `mvnun` that informs me how it calculates the CDF?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/mvndst.f

Comment: @BoboDarph yes, thanks. Seems I ignored the Fortran file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation is written in Fortran.  That `pyf` file defines the interface for the Fortran function in [mvndst.f](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/mvndst.f)

Comment: Oh, I ignored the Fortran file. Thanks, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

People using these routines from Alan Genz should reference and look at his papers for more information. This seems to be the one behind mvnun.
https://doi.org/10.2307/1390838
As of 2023, avalable here: https://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/papers/mvn.pdf